# Cant use directive controller values in directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, attributes

Im having a hard time accessing the attributes passed in to my directive from the template of that directive. I want to be able to access 'companyId' from album.tmpl.html but no matter what i try i can't get it. The strangest part is i can see it has made its way in to the controller, but somehow it's not getting from the controller to the template. I know the template is correctly calling the controller as it can succesfully print out the value of 'testVar' which is initialised inside the controller. Any advice would be appreciated.

**directive + directive controller**

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('erCommon')
    .directive('erAlbum', albumDirective)
    .controller('AlbumController', AlbumController);

function AlbumController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.testVar = "test var initiated";
}

function albumDirective($log) {
    function albumLink(scope, element, attrs, AlbumController) {
        //watch vars in here
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            companyId: '=companyId'
        },
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl: 'components/temp/album.tmpl.html',
        controller: 'AlbumController',
        controllerAs: 'albumCtrl',
        link: albumLink
    };
}

})();
```

**template ( album.tmpl.html**

```
 <div ng-controller="AlbumController as albumCtrl">
    testVar: {{albumCtrl.testVar}}<BR>
    companyId:{{albumCtrl.companyId}}<BR>
 </div>
```

**usage**

```
<er-album company-id="2"></er-album>
```

**output**

```
test var: test var initiated
companyId:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove ng-controller from your template:

```
<div>
    testVar: {{albumCtrl.testVar}}<BR>
    companyId:{{albumCtrl.companyId}}<BR>
</div>
```

Comment: brilliant, thank you, that was the problem. Of course i am already binding the controller to the template when i create the directive so ng-controller was completely unnecessary but Im still not sure why using ng-controller is causing issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the result you wanted i had to modify the structure of your code slightly. Hope this helps you to understand the issue. Look for materials about isolated scopes which Angular uses with directives.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="erCommon" ng-controller="AlbumController as albumCtrl">
  <er-album company-id="2" test = "albumCtrl.testVar"></er-album>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('erCommon', [])
    .directive('erAlbum', albumDirective)
    .controller('AlbumController', AlbumController);

function AlbumController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.testVar = "test var initiated";
}

function albumDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            test: '=test',
            companyId: '@companyId'
        },
        template: '<div> testVar: {{test}}<BR> companyId:{{companyId}}<BR> </div>', // it will work fine with templateUrl as well, just didn't want to cr8 another file...
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
          //do whatever else you might need;
        }
    };
}
```